# Is it OK to use "what" to refer to a place in noun clauses?

Tags: clauses

I came across the following sentence in my English test paper:

> It is the best for this kind of plant to grow in what is warm and rainy.

According to my teacher, it should mean

> It is the best for this kind of plant to grow in the place that is warm and rainy.

However, I think it sounds a little weird, as I've never heard of anyone using "what" to refer to a place in a noun clause. So is it grammatically correct (or OK) to say so?

(PS: Actually, I am not a native English speaker. So is my teacher. Please forgive her if it is not OK :))

Comment: Your teacher is right. Leaving aside the fused relative construction, "what" is not ordinarily allowed in relative clauses in Standard English. With a minimum change in wording, I would prefer: "It is best for this kind of plant to grow in a place that is warm and rainy".

Comment: @BillJ Oh yeah, I have just had a discussion with my teacher. I think it _is_ grammatically correct. Actually, according to my teacher, the sentence was originally from Chinese _gaokao_. (Maybe I should ask the people from [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)?) However, in my opinion, lots of sentences in _gaokao_ sound quite artificial compared with those on the Internet and in the books, though they’re grammatically correct...

Comment: Yes, it would be OK, but it would be a 'fused' relative construction, meaning "plant to grow in "that which is warm and rainy". I did mention in my first comment that I was leaving the 'fused' relative construction aside, since it is a somewhat more advanced form of relative construction.

Comment: @lhy7889678 The problem with the sentence is not the use of **what**, that's fine. The problem is that lack of a noun at the end. *It grows in warm and rainy* is ungrammatical. If you add *conditions* (or some other noun) to the end, then it's fine. You can debate the function of *what*, but if you added *conditions* to the end of the sentence it would address any criticism—aside from the fact that I think it should actually be (1) *in what **are** warm and rainy* ***conditions*** or (2) *in what **is a** warm and rainy* ***condition***.

Comment: But discussion of it being grammatical aside, it's not idiomatic. Far more common is simply what I used in the first part of my comment with *conditions*, and dropping *what* altogether.

Comment: @BillJ Maybe you misunderstood me... I understand that it is a noun clause (or fused relative construction, maybe the terminology we're using at school is old-fashioned). What I'm concerning about is whether we can use "what" to refer to a "place". I did some further investigations online. (I don't have a printed Eng-Eng dictionary.) The definition at lexico.com says it means "the thing or things that" if used this way. Can a place be a "thing"? Wiktionary and Merriam-Webster say it can also mean "that which", and this seems OK. Confusing... Do we really apply this construction to a place?

Comment: @Jason Bassford Well, you may be right, though the English experts in China for _gaokao_ won't agree with you... Sometimes they are stubborn; the grammar they're using may be old-fashioned and far from reality... (For example, they claim _The reason why ... is because ..._ is ungrammatical, though there have been debates on this for decades...) In fact, I really what a technical explanation, though I _have to_ follow the experts and the textbooks for _gaokao_...

Comment: No, you can't -- that is the point I was trying to make. I gave you my suggestion in my first comment, i.e. "It is best for this kind of plant to grow in a place that is warm and rainy".

Comment: @lhy7889678 I'm confused. If you are following what the "English experts in China" say, then why are you bothering to ask any of us our opinion?

Comment: "What" can refer to places, as in "The hotel turned out to be what was undeniably a complete dump", but note the all-important noun phrase at the end.

Comment: It is more commonly used with objects, as in "I've eaten what you gave me", meaning "that which you gave me.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Well, I think learning English is something more than just getting through a test, so despite the fact that I have to follow them, I want to know what people will _really_ say. (It's my first time to post here so I offer my apology if I was doing something wrong.)

Comment: Despite the terminology gaps, my conclusions are: (1) the word "the" before "best" had better be deleted, (2) if "what" is used this way, a noun (phrase) should be put at the end and (3) "what" can refer to a place sometimes. (Feel free to close or edit the questions if you think they're some issues with the question...)

Comment: After all, since it's not idiomatic, I will never use such kind of expression in _actual_ communication. Thanks to your explanations and, I'm sorry if I had wasted your precious time.